# How to find unused applications

Tags: applications

I want to uninstall unused applications.

BTW : I don't have goople playstore installed nor use a google account, I use [yalp](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) or [aurora](https://f-droid.org/fr/packages/com.dragons.aurora/) stores to install applications.

How can I find the unused applications that are installed on my smartphone ?

Answer (score 2):

Android since 5.0/6.0 contains an integrated app usage statistics system. It tracks which app is used when and how long.

The data collected by this system can be accessed by every app with the correct permissions - therefore you can find a lot of apps that are able to display the [app usage of your device](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=app%20Usage&c=apps).

Based on this information you can easily find out which app(s) you have not used for a certain period of time.